# Android Listview Scroll Behavior Scroll on fast fling/move otherwise not

Tags: android, android-listview, android-view, android-scrollview, android-gesture

I want a create a Custom ListView which will have following behavior,
1. When I scroll my finger on List It Should not Scroll by itself.
2. When User has finger down and moving finger slowly then ListView should pass touch event to Child and child will show ListView Icon Name.
3. When User moves finger with some threshold velocity or fast enough, List Will Scroll and show user next Items in List.

To achieve this I tried to override dispatchTouchEvent method from ListView as follows,

```
    @Override 
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) 
{ 
    if(ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
    {
        int height = getHeight();
        if((height - ev.getY())<100)//when finger is moving downwards
        {
            smoothScrollBy(50, 100);
        }
        if(ev.getY()<100)// when finger moves upwards.
        {

                smoothScrollBy(-50,100);
        }
        return true;
    }
     return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
  }
```

In above implementation I can move finger to certain point and list scrolls by 50 pixels over 100 ms. Here I can not get ListView Flings and speed. So I tried to add a GestureListner to ListView in it's OnTouchEvent() method. But in I get only first OnFling after that I do not get any touch movement.
Can some one guide me make such ListView or any other scroll view with such behavior.
Thanks.

Comment: You must have built it. one year has been passed. Please share your solution